# Books by Sri PanchAnan Bhattacharya

Tags: gita, kriyayoga

Sri Pamchanan was the chief disciple of Sri LAhIrI mahAshaya.

Very well known for his geeta commentary.

I would like to know about all books penned by him and if any of these available online as pdf version

Comment: Srimad Bhagavad Gita Yogacharya book was there on archive.org but , it looks that it is been removed from there - https://archive.org/details/SrimadBhagavadGitaYogacharyaPanchananBhattacharya1984Hindi_201802 . Mahabharatam in Bengali - https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.291485/page/n3

Comment: looks like researching on authors these days. :-D

Comment: @SwiftPushkar i m into kriya yoga already

Answer (score 3):

It seems you can order books by him and on him from this website:

https://sanskritclassics.com/new_releases.html

(Shipping to India though...)

Answer (score 2):

These books are available online : https://www.amazon.in/Books-Panchanan-Bhattacharya/s?ie=UTF8&page=1&rh=n%3A976389031%2Cp_27%3APanchanan%20Bhattacharya

and [https://www.amazon.com/Amazing-Autobiography-Siddha-Yogi-Bhattacharya/dp/1877854557](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1877854557)

and https://www.amazon.in/Yogacharya-Sri-Panchanan-Bhattacharya/dp/1877854484

I could not get the list of all His books.I shall search for His bengali books and update.But probably these if any are not yet been translated.